# Ajax Serialize Not Getting All Values of form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

So i have `form` having some input fieldd and it is submitting via `Ajax Serialize`.
The problem is It is not taking all the values of the form in `serialize output`.I know i have give `Name` for each field, Here is my code for HTML :

```
<form action="" id="BindData">
        <input type="hidden" name='style_id' id='style_id' value="<?php echo $model->style_id; ?>">  
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Select Category:</span>
                <select id="category" name="cat_id" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                    <?php foreach($all_categories['models'] as $Category) { ?>    
                    <option value="<?php echo $Category->category_id; ?>"><?php echo $Category->category_name;  ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group tr_sub_cat" style="display:none;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Select SubCategory:</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="sub_category"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Weightage:</span>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <input type="text" name="weightage" id="weightage" class="form-control" value="0"><span class="badge bg-red">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addBind pull-left">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

In My Above code The serialize method is not taking the values of `cat_id` & `weightage` while i have given them `name`.
The sub category loaded from `cat_id` select box is coming in serialize data and changes in weightage value is not coming in out put.
Here is my output of serialize :

```
style_id=1&cat_id=&sub_cat=95&weightage=0
```

`cat_id` is blank and `weightage` is still `0`, not the updated one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use val function to collect data from inputs:

```
var cat =  $("#cat_id").val();
var weightage =  $("#weightage").val();
```

you shouldn't have to do it manually for every field. That's what serialize is for.
you can use above code for debugging to check correct form value save in variable or not.

Comment: Values are coming using this approch